# How to define a function-local type alias of the function's type parameters (or their associated types)?

Tags: rust, type-alias

I have a generic function `foo` with some complex-ish trait bounds:

```
use std::ops::Index;

// This trait is just as an example
trait Float {
    const PI: Self;
    fn from_f32(v: f32) -> Self;
}
// impl Float for f32, f64 ...

fn foo<C>(container: &C)
where
    C: Index<u32>,
    <C as Index<u32>>::Output: Float,
{
    // ...
}
```

I now need to use the type `<C as Index<u32>>::Output` inside the function a bunch (e.g. to get π via `::PI` or say `::from_f32(3.0)`). But this type is long to type out by hand and makes the whole code very verbose and hard to read. (*Note*: in my real code, the actual type is even longer and more ugly.)

To solve this, I tried to create a function local type alias:

```
// Inside of `foo`:
type Floaty = <C as Index<u32>>::Output;
```

But this results in this error:

```
error[E0401]: can't use type parameters from outer function
  --> src/lib.rs:16:20
   |
10 | fn foo<C>(container: &C)
   |    --- - type variable from outer function
   |    |
   |    try adding a local type parameter in this method instead
...
16 |     type Floaty = <C as Index<u32>>::Output;
   |                    ^ use of type variable from outer function
```

So, just like other items, `type` aliases are also treated regardless of whether they are in a function or not. Not having any good ideas, I tried to write a macro that expands to the type:

```
// Inside of `foo`:
macro_rules! Floaty {
    () => { <C as Index<u32>>::Output };
}

Floaty!()::PI;    // errors
```

While I had partial success with this (`Floaty!()` is valid in some type contexts), this last line errors with:

```
error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `::`
  --> src/lib.rs:20:14
   |
20 |     Floaty!()::PI;    // errors
   |              ^^ expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator here

error[E0575]: expected method or associated constant, found associated type `Index::Output`
  --> src/lib.rs:17:17
   |
17 |         () => { <C as Index<u32>>::Output };
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
20 |     Floaty!()::PI;    // errors
   |     --------- in this macro invocation
   |
   = note: can't use a type alias as a constructor
```

---

None of my attempts worked completely. **Is it possible to avoid writing out the full type name each time?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diesel has a similar "problem" and they've solved it by [defining non-function-local type aliases](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.1/diesel/helper_types/index.html). I like this solution because you can use the alias to clean up your trait bounds as well:

```
type Floaty<C> = <C as Index<u32>>::Output;

fn foo<C>(container: &C)
where
    C: Index<u32>,
    Floaty<C>: Float,
{
    let p = Floaty::<C>::PI;
    // ...
}
```

Note that you'll have to change your trait `Float` to require that it's `Sized` in order to actually run this code.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I have seen this done is to add the type as another type parameter to the function.

```
fn foo<F, C>(container: &C)
where
    F: Float,
    C: Index<u32, Output = F>,
{
    let pi = F::PI;
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't usually cause problems with type inference, as there will only be one type `F` that works for a given `C` (at least in this example), but it does make certain uses noisier, since to specify the type `F` you have to also put a placeholder for `C` and vice versa.